# jstl, retrieving arraylist of objects in jsp from servlet inside <script> tags

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I have an arraylist of objects from my backend which arrives in my servlet. From there I send it to a jsp page where I want to use it from inside a `<script></script>`. I have tried using:

```
request.setAttribute("locations",DatabaseRetriever.getLocations(diatoms));
request.getRequestDispatcher("mapPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

with `request.getAttribute("locations")` I am able to access it outside the `<script></script>` tags or inside `<script>` with

```
<% List<Location> locations = (ArrayList<Location>)request.getAttribute("locations");
```

. But then I still don't know how to access it from outside the <% %> tags and inside `<script>`.
I tried using jstl with the ${} tags, but I can't seem to get that working.

So to summarize, I want to access an arraylist of objects sent from my servlet to my jsp from inside my `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: *I want to access an arraylist of objects sent from my servlet to my jsp from inside my `<script></script>` tags.* You can't. Servlets and JSPs run on the server, Javascript runs in the browser. What you can do is write the array list in the page in some form that will later be available to the Javascript to use when running in the browser. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Bogdan I am using openlayers and openstreetmap to visualise a map in the frontend, in that map i want to place markers and for that i need coordinates and location names from my database. But the whole openlayers and openstreetmap runs inside ```<script></script>``` tags in the jsp page. That's why i want to be able to acces my arraylist of objects from inside the tags. I hope that made it a bit clearer.